# if this attribute value is enclosed in quotation marks the quotation marks must match error

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to design a Responsive Image slider with thumbnails.
Here is the code.

```
 <div class="cycle-slideshow"
     data-cycle-timeout=0
     data-cycle-pager="#pager2"
     data-cycle-pager-template="<span><img src={{firstChild.src}}/></span>"

>
    <span class="cycle-pager"></span>
    <span class="cycle-prev">&#9001;</span>
    <span class="cycle-next">&#9002;</span>
    <img src="Images/BackgroundAlternate.jpg" />
    <img src="Images/LogOut.jpg" />
    <img src="Images/BackgroundAlternate1.jpg" />
    <img src="Images/BackgroundAlternate2.jpg" />
    <img src="Images/BackgroundAlternate.jpg" />

</div>
```

while adding that span tag to the attribute `data-cycle-pager-template`, I am getting an error as

> if this attribute value is enclosed in quotation marks the quotation marks must match

Why is that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes to the img src within the attribute `data-cycle-pager-template` and let the value of `firstChild.src` bind to a source without any quotes:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
     data-cycle-timeout=0
     data-cycle-pager="#pager2"
     data-cycle-pager-template="<span><img src='{{firstChild.src}}'/></span>">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it. But still the same problem occurs @KAD

Comment: what is the source value that is under firstChild?